# Ansible: Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.9.27. Target is Linux CentOs7

'become sudo' always fails with the error `Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt`

When I try manually, sudo su takes about 60 seconds to return a prompt. I don't know why, but I'd like to know how to change the timeout so that Ansible waits more time for become.

I've tried different solutions I found in StackOverflow, such as running with `-c paramiko`, but they didn't work.

`<myhostname.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: myuserid`

`<myhostname.com> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d8 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="myuserid"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/home/myuserid/.ansible/xx/e123e1234e myhostname.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /tmp/myuserid/ansible/ansible-tmp-12334567890/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''`

`<myhostname.com> (0, '', '')`

`fatal: [myhostname.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: \r\n"`

Comment: The issue got fixed in the server side configuration , and I didn't see this problem anymore.

Comment: Hey @freeAR how did you fixed at the server side what configuration has modified? This helps other to learn on this issue. So kindly post the changes you have made for ansible.cfg file or any other file?

Answer (score 1):

The above with:

```
export ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT=120;
```

...works perfectly. But If you want to ensure this from the Ansible configuration instead, you can add these two lines in your (./)ansible.cfg:

```
timeout = 60
gather_timeout = 60
```

This has the same result as the export bit. You may have to change the timeout number in seconds to accommodate your needs. Mine is for a slow Raspberry Pi with high yescrypt hash rounds on the user to use ansible_become.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, one way is to set environment variable as below

```
export ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT=120;
```

Run the playbook on same terminal where environment variable is set.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get a chance to try this setting. I don't know if it would have fixed the problem I was observing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't approve of increasing the timeout...

I had a thought while I was searching for a resolution to this error... I'd seen a sudo prompt take time in the past due to the mismatched hostname in /etc/hosts.

Resolving that name mismatch resolved the timeout issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).